# How to get the executable given only the hex code?

Tags: windows, assembly, binary, hex, masm

I am learning windows assembly language with `masm` as my assembler and `link` as my linker. I  took the following assembly code and obtained the exe

```
.386                                                                                 
.model flat, stdcall                                                                 
option casemap :none                                                                 

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC                                                          
extrn ExitProcess@4  : PROC                                                          

.code                                                                                
start:                                                                               
        mov eax, 0                                                                   
        push eax                                                                     
        jmp msg                                                                      
pgm:    pop ebx                                                                      
        push ebx                                                                     
        push ebx                                                                     
        push eax                                                                     
        call MessageBoxA@16                                                          
        push eax                                                                     
        call ExitProcess@4                                                           
msg:    call pgm                                                                     
        db "KingKong",0                                                              
end start

C:\Arena>ml /c /coff  a.asm                                                         
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 10.00.30319.01                                
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                          

 Assembling: a.asm   

C:\Arena>link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32 /defaultlib:user32 a.obj      
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01                             
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The program works fine and displays the message box, Now I ran a `objdump -d a.exe` and obtain the shellcode and inserted it back to obtain the executable as

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC
extrn ExitProcess@4  : PROC

.code
start:
db 0xb8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50,0xeb,0x0f,0x5b,0x53,0x53,0x50,0xe8,0x1b,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50,0xe8,0x0f,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xe8,0xec,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x4b,0x69,0x6e,0x67,0x4b,0x6f,0x6e,0x67,0x00,0xcc,0xff,0x25,0x00,0x20,0x40,0x00,0xff,0x25,0x08,0x20,0x40,0x00
end start
```

but when I try to assemble it I get

```
C:\Arena>ml /c /coff b.asm                                                          
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 10.00.30319.01                                
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                          

 Assembling: b.asm                                                                  
b.asm(10) : error A2042:statement too complex
```

I was able to get back the executable with the hexdump on linux and that thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915724/how-to-create-a-binary-executable-using-hex). I need to get back the executable using only the hexdump I obtained on windows now. How do I do it ?

**EDIT** It was a nice suggestion to split the byte and I have

```
.386                                                                                 
.model flat, stdcall                                                                 
option casemap :none                                                                 

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC                                                          
extrn ExitProcess@4  : PROC                                                          

.code                                                                                
start:                                                                               
db 0xb8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x50,0xeb,0x0f                                           
db 0x5b,0x53,0x53,0x50,0xe8,0x1b,0x00,0x00                                           
db 0x00,0x50,0xe8,0x0f,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xe8                                           
db 0xec,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x4b,0x69,0x6e,0x67                                           
db 0x4b,0x6f,0x6e,0x67,0x00,0xcc,0xff,0x25                                           
db 0x00,0x20,0x40,0x00,0xff,0x25,0x08,0x20                                           
db 0x40,0x00                                                                         
end start
```

but when I feed this to assembler I get

```
C:\Arena>ml a.asm                                                                   
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 10.00.30319.01                                
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                          

 Assembling: a.asm                                                                  
a.asm(10) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(11) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(12) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(13) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(14) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(15) : error A2206:missing operator in expression                              
a.asm(16) : error A2206:missing operator in expression
```

*How do I get back the executable given only the hex code ?*

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for MessageBoxA and ExitProcess should look like this (unfortunately I normally use GNU assembler so I do not know if the syntax here is correct):

```
  db 0b8h, 000h, 000h, 000h, 000h, 050h, 0ebh, 00fh
  db 05bh, 053h, 053h, 050h, 0e8h
  dd MessageBoxA@16 - addr1
addr1:
  db 050h, 0e8h
  dd ExitProcess@4 - addr2
addr2:
  db 0e8h, 0ech, 0ffh, 0ffh, 0ffh, 04bh, 069h, 06eh
...
```

You cannot "just" use hex. code when you do not know the addresses of the functions you call!

Maybe MASM does not even allow relative addresses to be created using a "dd" pseudo-instruction. In this case you have one possibility:

```
mov ECX, MessageBoxA@16
call ECX
```

This will result in an absolute address ("call" uses relative ones) so when translated to hex code the file would look like this:

```
db 0b9h
dd MessageBoxA@16
db 0ffh, 0d1h
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain `masm` has a line length limit (255 from memory, at least for the versions I used).

You need to split that big honking `db` statement into multiple ones. In other words, do something like (you'll also notice I've changed the contents to my peferred style - I have no idea whether `masm` accepts C-style hex numbers, I've never used them):

```
.code
start:
    db 0b8h,  00h,  00h,  00h,  00h,  50h, 0ebh,  0fh
    db  5bh,  53h,  53h,  50h, 0e8h,  1bh,  00h,  00h
    ; and so on
```

However, I'm not *entirely* confident that the external calls to `MessageBox` and `ExitProcess` will work with the byte-based solution, you'll need to check that.

Comment: have a look at my edit, I tried your suggestion but still could not get it working !!!, and could you please suggest some workarounds for the `MessageBox` and `ExitProcess`

Comment: @vikkyhacks, indent your `db` statements and try changing the formatting.